# Shift entire column on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I want to shift to the right an entire column, fill with NAN the first column and drop the last column:

```
df0:             A  B  C  D
    2013-12-31   10 6  6  5        
    2014-01-31   11 7  5  5
    2014-02-28   15 8  8  8
```

into

```
df1:             A   B  C  D
    2013-12-31   NaN 10 6  6          
    2014-01-31   NaN 11 7  5  
    2014-02-28   NaN 15 8  8
```

My solution is to split the columns into Series and then recompose the dataframe.
Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) shift the data by rows. Here's my trick

```
df.T.shift().T
```

#### Update

It's a bug when passing axis as 1. It's been solved in the current develop version. If you are living in the cutting edge, use

```
df.shift(axis=1)
```

instead.

Comment: I would've posted this as an answer but it looked inelegant, can you explain why `df.shift(axis=1)` does not work?

Comment: with df.shift.(axis=1) I get an error: IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4... the solution from waitingkuo is great!

Comment: @waitingkuo yes I just tried an example with 4 rows and noticed it shifted correctly with `axis=1` but put `NaN` in the first row rather than first column, good to know these bugs are fixed in next version

Comment: over 1 year later and there is still a bug.