# remove initial NaNs from dataframe whilst keeping others in place

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, nan

Please help! I have done some research and these questions are linked however I can't massage this to work:
[Multiple shifts on dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598215/multiple-shifts-on-dataframe)
[Shift entire column on a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105197/shift-entire-column-on-a-pandas-dataframe)
[Remove NaNs from DataFrame and duplicates from multi-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772920/remove-nans-from-dataframe-and-duplicates-from-multi-index)

This is the closest to my problem:
[Shift rows to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45049055/shift-rows-to-left?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

**My problem:** Time series problem so I want to shift the rows to the left if the first entry is NaN, whilst keeping any other NaNs in that row after the inital first value where they are.

So starting DataFrame like this:

```
  A     B     C     D
1 10    11    23    90
2 NaN   05    NaN   56
3 11    3     Nan   11
4 NaN   NaN   56    NaN`
```

My solution I have is wrong, it looks like this:

```
df3 = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values),1)
df3.columns=df2.columns[:len(df3.columns)]
df3= df3.reindex_axis(df2.columns,1)
```

This gives **(not what I want!)**:

```
  A     B     C     D
1 10    11    23    90
2 05    56    NaN   NaN
3 11    3     11    NaN
4 56    NaN   NaN   NaN
```

**I would please like a DataFrame like this:**

```
  A     B     C     D
1 10    11    23    90
2 05    NaN   56    NaN
3 11    3     NaN   11
4 56    NaN   NaN   NaN
```

So the leading edge `NaNs` are removed, but once that first measurement is taken, any subsequent `NaNs` are left in their place.

Thank you very much for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
In [57]: df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.notnull().values.argmax()), axis=1)
Out[57]: 
      A     B     C     D
1  10.0  11.0  23.0  90.0
2   5.0   NaN  56.0   NaN
3  11.0   3.0   NaN  11.0
4  56.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

---

This works by shifting over as many cells as necessary to bring the first non-null value to the left:

```
In [63]: x = df.iloc[1]

In [64]: x
Out[64]: 
A     NaN
B     5.0
C     NaN
D    56.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64

In [65]: x.notnull()
Out[65]: 
A    False
B     True
C    False
D     True
Name: 2, dtype: bool

In [66]: x.notnull().values
Out[66]: array([False,  True, False,  True])

In [67]: x.notnull().values.argmax()
Out[67]: 1

In [68]: x.shift(-x.notnull().values.argmax())
Out[68]: 
A     5.0
B     NaN
C    56.0
D     NaN
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation, really helpful.